# React/Redux, calling method from a model throws TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to run the formatAddress from the Model, to display the address in a formatted way, but it throws TypeError whenever that method is called.

Component

```
export const PostRow: React.FC<Props> = ({ index, userIndex }) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const { name, username, email, formatAddress } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.users[userIndex])
    console.log(formatAddress())
```

Reducer

```
export const userReducer: Reducer<UserState, UserActions> = (state: UserState = [], action: UserActions): UserState => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case UserActionTypes.GET_ALL_USERS:
            return action.payload.map((user: UserResponseDTO) => (new User(user)))
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Model

```
export class User {
    public id: number
    public name: string
    public username: string
    public email: string
    public address: UserAdress
    public phone: string
    public website: string
    public company: UserCompany

    constructor(userDTO: UserResponseDTO) {
        this.id = userDTO.id
        this.name = userDTO.name
        this.username = userDTO.username
        this.email = userDTO.email
        this.address = userDTO.address
        this.phone = userDTO.phone
        this.website = userDTO.website
        this.company = userDTO.company
    }

    formatAddress() {
        return `${this.address.street}. ${this.address.city} - ${this.address.zipcode}`
    }
}
```

Returns

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
```

Comment: Can't you map inside the React Component vs the Reducer?

Comment: I guess a good starting point is to comment out both the address and the company in the constructor. That way you will be able to locate if the error is originating in the components UserAdress or UserCompany.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For regular functions, the value of `this` is determined by how the function is called. Since you've saved formatAddress to a variable and then called it with the code `formatAddress()`, it is being called without any context. As a result, `this` defaults to undefined (or in non-strict mode, to the window object).

One option is to change how you're calling it. If you save the user object and then call `user.formatAddress()`, then `this` will be set equal to the user:

```
const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.users[userIndex]);
console.log(user.formatAddress());
```

Alternatively, you can bind formatAddress to the user. This creates a new function who's value of `this` is permanently baked in:

```
constructor(userDTO: UserResponseDTO) {
  this.id = userDTO.id
  // ... etc
  this.company = userDTO.company
  this.formatAddress = this.formatAddress.bind(this);
}
```

Or use an arrow function, since they get their `this` from what `this` was equal to when the arrow function was created. Since you're using typescript, you can use the following syntax:

```
export class User {
  // ... stuff omitted
  constructor(userDTO: UserResponseDTO) {
    //...
  }

  formatAddress = () => {
    return `${this.address.street}. ${this.address.city} - ${this.address.zipcode}`
  }
}
```